# Error: Cannot find module 'nexmo' & error TS2307: Cannot find module nexmo

Tags: javascript, typescript, requirejs, nestjs, vonage

so I'm working with the **NestJs** Framework and **typescript**.

I was asked to add two factor authentication (SMS) using the node library of **Nexmo**.
Here is a link from their website: https://dashboard.nexmo.com/getting-started/verify

Everything worked as promised while in development mode.

But when I tried to build for production I got this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'nexmo'
```

So I started googling about it.

I first read about **import vs require**.

Almost everything in my NestJs project works with import.

But I remember using require sometimes with no problem.
For example when I had to use these two I had no problem:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const xml2js = require('xml2js');
```

Then I came across people that were having similar problems and they were able to solve them by modifying a bit their tsconfig.json.

Some added the **"moduleResolution": "node"** instead of **"moduleResolution": "classic"** while others changed the **"module": "commonjs"** to **"module": "AMD"**, or **"module": "ESNext"**

I tried all of these with no avail. Sometimes the error was changing from:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'nexmo'
```

to:

```
error TS2307: Cannot find module nexmo
```

Then I started reading here to understand more about this matter:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html

Again I couldn't find my solution.

A friend of mine told me to check something about installing **typings** but NestJs already uses **@types** which from what I read is a more updated version of typings.

Other than that I had no luck.
All I understand is that the project must be compiled to js from ts and that for some reason NestJs can't find the nexmo in the node_modules folder.

Can you help or direct me to the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok - tried a few things from a fresh install, and here is what I got to work:

//tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true, <- this seems to be the important one here
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true
  }
}
```

//app.controller.ts

```
import { Controller, Get } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import Nexmo from 'nexmo';

const nexmo = new Nexmo({
  apiKey: '',
  apiSecret: '',
});

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

  @Get()
  getHello(): string {
    console.log(nexmo.verify);
    return this.appService.getHello();
  }
}
```

I then ran

```
~/G/A/test-nest> master > nest build
~/G/A/test-nest >master >node ./dist/main
[Nest] 21347   - 08/19/2020, 11:36:27 AM   [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 21347   - 08/19/2020, 11:36:27 AM   [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +18ms
[Nest] 21347   - 08/19/2020, 11:36:27 AM   [RoutesResolver] AppController {}: +7ms
[Nest] 21347   - 08/19/2020, 11:36:27 AM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {, GET} route +3ms
[Nest] 21347   - 08/19/2020, 11:36:27 AM   [NestApplication] Nest application successfully started +3ms
```

Comment: Good callout, I always set "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,"esModuleInterop": true in every typescript project out of habit and didn't even think about mentioning those settings.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the Nexmo package on Github, I see here that it is exporting a default value from its main module: https://github.com/Nexmo/nexmo-node/blob/master/src/Nexmo.js#L175

This means in your typescript file you should be able to simply say:

```
import Nexmo from 'nexmo';
```

Some packages in npm are not commonjs friendly (meaning they are not node js module friendly) and in that case you would need to import that in typescript using this syntax:

```
import Nexmo = require('nexmo');
```

Give that first one a shot though and see if it works for you.